Unexplained BadForegroundServiceNotificationException in Crashlytics logs with varying layout references
I'm encountering a crash in production that I cannot reproduce locally. The crash is logged in Crashlytics as follows:
    Fatal Exception: android.app.RemoteServiceException$BadForegroundServiceNotificationException: Bad notification(tag=null, id=187544) posted from package com.example.android, crashing app(uid=10187, pid=18102): Couldn't inflate contentViewsandroid.widget.RemoteViews$ActionException: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #77 in com.example.android:layout/preference_widget_seekbar: Binary XML file line #77 in com.example.android:layout/preference_widget_seekbar: Error inflating class androidx.preference.UnPressableLinearLayout
   at android.app.ActivityThread.throwRemoteServiceException(ActivityThread.java:2019)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mthrowRemoteServiceException(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2275)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
   at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7937)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:569)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1019)

The exception references a layout file notification_content, but neither the foreground service nor the notification in my code uses this layout.
Interestingly, the referenced file name (layout/notification_content) changes in different crash logs, suggesting this may not directly relate to a specific file in my app.
The crash occurs on production devices only and is not reproducible in development or testing environments.
I’ve tried the following without success:

Verified that all my notification layouts are properly defined and
compatible across target SDKs.
Checked for any dynamically loaded or third-party components that
might interact with notifications.
Reviewed existing Stack Overflow answers and implemented all relevant
suggestions, such as ensuring all notification IDs are unique and
using valid RemoteViews layouts, but the issue persists.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue? Could this be related to:

A third-party library interfering with the notification system?
A system-level bug on certain Android versions or device
configurations?

Any insights or troubleshooting suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
